# IIS local IP access externally with public IP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, portforwarding, iis-10, web-application-firewall

I have an ASP.Net MVC project that is running under IIS. I can reach it using local IP and port. I bind it with my IP and port.

What should I do to reach it with my public IP and port like http://PUBLICIP:PORT

When I try to reach it says connection error with code 502.

This is what I tried so far.

- Adding my local IP to router's DMZ Adding
- Port forwarding with port and my local IP
- Add inbound and outbound rules to Firewall, inbound rules allow edge
  traversal.
- Turning off firewall, windows defender etc.

Do I need any features to install when I try to reach IIS externally?

Thanks all.

Comment: So, You want to access the website hosted on your local IIS from a public domain?

Comment: could you please share what is the sub status code?try to configure your routers port forwarding feature to forward requests for a different external port to local IIS port 80.are you behind some NAT? You can check it: run IPCONFIG on the server and have a look at its IP address; if it's different from the external one, then there's some NAT in the middle, and you need your provider to properly configure it.even if you have no firewall on your server and it's sitting on its public IP address, there actually could be some firewall in the middle, so you should check that with your provider, too.

Comment: you could refer this link for more detail:[link1](https://superuser.com/questions/282620/accessing-iis-externally)